# What is the conventional way to compute a sum of list of tuples in Python?

Tags: python, list, sum, tuples

Given a `list` of `tuple`-s, what is the conventional way to compute its sum?

We can define sum as a tuple in which every element is the sum of corresponding elements from all tuples in list.

For example, the sum of list `[(1, 4), (1, -4), (1, 4)]` is `(3, 4)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
data = [(1, 4), (1, -4), (1, 4)]
total_a = total_b = 0
for a,b in data:
    total_a += a
    total_b += b
print((total_a, total_b))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the indices of each tuple using `zip`:

```py
[sum(i) for i in zip(*list)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) from built-in module [`functools`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functools.html):

```py
from functools import reduce


l = [(1, 4), (1, -4), (1, 4)]
res = reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]), l)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by help of `numpy`:

```
import numpy

tuple(sum(numpy.array(list)))
# (3, 4)
```

Comment: Using numpy for built-in data structures is overkill